# Facebook JavaScript SDK - Login and Callback - transition from FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm transitioning from this style of login button

`<fb:login-button perms="publish_stream,read_stream,friends_location,email" onlogin="facebookLoginCallback();" size="large">`
   `<g:message code="Connect with Facebook"/>`
`</fb:login-button>`

to

`<div class="fb-login-button"
           data-show-faces="false" data-width="200"
           data-max-rows="1"
           data-onlogin="facebookLoginCallback();">Connect with Facebook</div>`

But the data-onlogin does not actually cause the facebookLoginCallback() to be called. This doesn't seem to be documented well. data-onlogin not documented, just my best guess at a translation. Is the property supposed to be called something else. It doesn't appear to translate to this newer recommended style. The login works - just not the callback. The first example's callback does work.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `FB.Event.subscribe`, in this case you'd want to listen to `auth.login` (here's the docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(r)
    {
        console.log(r.status);

        if ( r.status === 'connected' )
        {
            // a user has logged in
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FB.login` found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ - Quote: "...all apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 by October 1, 2011"

I've shared some code at: [Facebook requests 2.0 , how to change "Accept" button url to be a url outside of facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886134/facebook-requests-2-0-how-to-change-accept-button-url-to-be-a-url-outside-of) - see my answer at bottom. Good luck with migration.

Comment: Alvin, do you know why this happens or how one might fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060664/facebook-auth-js-sdk-is-broken-for-homescreend-webapps

Comment: First guess: scripting for pop-up window doesnt work in IOS, is there a debugger in IOS whereby you can trace the calls?

Comment: The problem with using FB.login is that you're not then using the standard login button but creating your own login UI.

Comment: Does this mean that FBML login button also is supposed to stop working in Oct. 2011? Some older code that I have still works.

Comment: No it doesn't, using FB.login is a JS SDK hook where you can call it through your code without having the user click on a FB UI button (eg either automatically or by using your own design). By using the method I suggested where you listen to the login event, you can continue to use the FBML style button and get proper callback when the user has logged in.